# position fixed not working on scroll down in chrome - inspector device

Tags: css

I think it's weird but, when I test my website on inspector web with Chrome tools my header in `position:fixed` not work. In all the other browser and screen dimension work good. Just in inspector web doesn't work.

```css
.site-header{ display: block;}
.header-top{
 background-color: #87b7bb;
 height: 90px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 00px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
}
.block{
    position:static;
 background-color: #000;
   height:1000px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header" >
  <div class="header-top">
  </div>
</div><!-- #masthead -->
<div class="block">
 <p> 

 </p>
</div>
```

When I use the inspector tools I can change all the setting and i see the changes, but fixed position not work.

Also, this happens only with scroll down. When i make scroll up i see the header move on the top on my windows in the right way.

Some one can help me?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link above to add a [mcve].

Comment: @JF so it's simple example, but of curse this work. I can not put all the code of my website here and also it's in localhost at moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding top: 0 to your `.header-top`?

In addition, instead of `width 100%`

have you tried using the following

```
.header-top{
  background-color: #87b7bb;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 00px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.66);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still not work, i think it's something about Chrome tools